# Can I remove actuator word from spring boot 2 actuator integration for health check

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, spring-boot-actuator, health-monitoring

I have used spring-boot-acturator for health check in my micro-services. And earlier my health api was:

```
mydomain:healthPort/health
```

Which are already integrated with Third party health check clients. Now after upgrading the spring-boot version to spring-boot 2 my health api became :

```
mydomain:healthPort/actuator/health
```

Is there any way , thus I can remove the **actuator** word from the health check api. Following are my health check configurations:

```
management:
  server:
    context-path: /
    port: 50186
  health.diskspace.enabled: false
  security:
    enabled: false
  endpoints:
    enabled-by-default: false
  endpoint:
    health:
      enabled: true
      show-details: always
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For completeness... Building on Arpan's answer, here's the `application.properties` way of doing it:

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
```

And the `application.yml` way:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /
```

Answer (score 9):

After some searching , I got the solution. Posting here, as it may be save some time for someone else:

```
management:
    endpoints:
        enabled-by-default: false
        web:
            base-path: /
            path-mapping.health: health
    endpoint:
        health.enabled: true
        health.show-details: always
    server.port: 50186
```

This mapping will solve the problem, mainly the following part is remapping the url:

management:
        endpoints:

```
        web:
            base-path: /
            path-mapping.health: health
```